# How to make a custom function on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am developing a discord bot, and I have to use **following function :**

```
async def get_ox(author,my_msg):
    ox = ['⭕', '❌']
    for i in ox:
        await my_msg.add_reaction(i)
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == author and str(reaction) in ox
    try:
        reaction = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=10.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return False
    else:
        reaction = reaction[0]
    if str(reaction)==ox[1]:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

But it definitely does not work, and **just returns True.**
How can I make it?

Comment: Please specify when it returns True. Does it so after a reaction has been added or immediatly after executing the function?

Comment: as Lu M said does the reaction part work or not?

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: I want the message.author to react on my_msg and I get the reaction O or X. Even the reaction part does not work, and I call it like `my_msg=await message.channel.send() ; if not get_ox(message.author, my_msg) : await message.channel.send('canceled.');return` @LuM @AhmedKhaled @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 1):

My problem was `await`.
I had to call the function like : `await get_ox(message.author, my_msg)`

Comment: You never showed where you were executing this function, which is why nobody was able to help you with this question. Please always include all of your relevant code.